# ImportError: /usr/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

when i run tf-gpu in linux ,i get a error 'ImportError: /usr/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by  site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)',i try fix ,but it can not run, the detail following:

python version 3.6
tenosrflow-gpu version 1.14
CUDA version 11.4
how can i fix bug

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @xy z, as per the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), tensorflow-gpu 1.14 is compatible with CUDA 10.0 and CUDNN 7.4. Please downgrade the CUDA version and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!